# C# creating an object using an array as the basis?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

This is more a question of whether this is possible.

I have an input box, 6 items go into the input box, this is an example string that forms the array:

Monday, Tuesday, April, February, Tomorrow, 42

These words can change, but their order is important. They are separated by a tab.

I want the 1st, 3rd, and the 6th word from this array. I would like to place them into an object - and if at all possible, but other items from other sources into that object in a particular order - so that I can then refer back to that object so that I do not have to write out long sections of code each time I need to output these 3 items.

My current code is unwieldy and I am looking for a better solution.

For reference my current code:

```
string phrase = value.Text;
string[] words = phrase.Split('\t');

string Word1 = words[1];
string Word2 = words[3];
string Word3 = words[6];

this.Output.Text = Word1 + '\t';
this.Output.Text += TextBox1.Text + '\t';
this.Output.Text += Word2 + '\t';
this.Output.Text += TextBox2.Text + '\t';
this.Output.Text += Word3;
```

This code works, but I am starting to work with larger arrays, requiring larger outputs and I am finding that I need to refer back to the same output multiple times.

Imagine the above code running to Word12, from an array of 30 adding the information from 6 text boxes, and having to have that output created 15 times in different places in the program. Also, you can see that the length of the code stops making sense.

If I could create an object containing all of that information, I could create it once, and then refer back to it as often as I needed.

Any insight or direction on how to proceed gratefully received.

Comment: Is there a pattern for which objects belong where or are they all manual?

Comment: So this is the 3rd time you've tried to ask this question? How are the values getting into the input box? Why one input box? Step back and look at the big picture. Ignore the UI problem, write the code you actually want to deal with first. Then map those concepts onto the UI.

Comment: Why are you trying to store only certain input words and not others? Does there need to be any validation against those words e.g. should the first 2 always be days of the week? It would be great if you could give a high level of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Austin, yes, I think the two answers below have told me where I need to go, I didn't find anything on indexes in my search. Jeremy, yes, because while the help I received certainly made my code work previously, they resulted in the above (which I simplified down so that people could follow).  sr28, no that was a random set - I think indexes sounds like a good way forward as they are always in position 1, 3 and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding you are looking for below solution. If I missed something then please let me know.

1. Firstly you can store value.Text into a list of string by splitting by '\t'.
2. Create an array to store indexes for which you want to pick words.
3. Based on stored indexes you can pick words and store in a final wordslist.
4. Create an array to store dynamic textboxes text.
5. Loop on these stored textboxes text array and insert at alternate position in final wordlist.
6. At last join wordlist separated by '\t' and show as output.

Below is the code:

```
string finalOutput = string.Empty;
        List<string> wordsList = new List<string>();
        string phrase = value.Text;// "Monday\tTuesday\tApril\tFebruary\tTomorrow\t42";
        string[] words = phrase.Split('\t');
        List<int> wordsIndexes = new List<int> { 1, 3, 6 }; //this is based on ur requirment
        List<string> textBoxesText = new List<string>() { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text };
        wordsIndexes.ForEach(i => wordsList.Add(words[i-1]));

        int insertAtIndex = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < textBoxesText.Count; i++)
        {
            if (wordsList.Count >= insertAtIndex)
            {
                wordsList.Insert(insertAtIndex, textBoxesText[i]);
                insertAtIndex += 2;
            }
        }

        finalOutput = string.Join('\t', wordsList);
```

Comment: Hi Vikas, this is really good, I think this absolutely what I will need to make my life better.  Oddly, my original question was 'Grouby using the count of words in an array' because I just had not encountered indexes and for all my searching, I never came across it.  So thank you for realising what I needed and providing code I can learn from.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but I think that you could use a list and add the words there, using a list of indexes like so:

```
string phrase = value.Text;
string[] words = phrase.Split('\t');
List<int> indexes = new List<int> { 1, 3, 6 }; //you can add more indexes here...
List<string> wordsList = new List<string>();
indexes.Foreach(i => wordsList.add(words[i]));
```

With this implementation, you have all the words you need in the list and you can easily add more just adding or removing any index you want. And you can refer the list whenever you need to.